# Is there an equivalent to MS SQL 'FOR XML PATH' in other database products?

Tags: sql, xml

I am currently using Microsoft's FOR XML PATH feature to pull data back from MS SQL Server in an XML format.  I really like the feature but am always uncomfortable about using vendor specific functions.

Do any of the other major database vendors have something similar?

### Edit

Let me be more specific with type of features I'm looking for

In MS SQL you can use this query

```
SELECT so.id AS '@Id',
       so.Code AS '@Code',  
       cu.Code AS 'Customer/@Code',
       cu.Name AS 'Customer/@Name',
       (SELECT Item_Num AS '@Item',
                pa.Code AS '@PartCode'
        FROM tblSalesItem si
            LEFT JOIN tblPart pa ON pa.Id = si.Part_Id
        WHERE si.SalesOrder_ID = so.Id 
        FOR XML PATH('SalesItem') , type) 
FROM tblSalesOrder so
    JOIN tblCustomer cu ON so.customer_id = cu.ID
FOR XML PATH('SalesOrder'), ROOT('SalesOrders')
```

to generate this XML

```
<SalesOrders>
  <SalesOrder Id="13" Code="C1002     ">
    <Customer Code="ROBERTS   " Name="Roberts Equipment  Inc." />
    <SalesItem Item="1" PartCode="FP-0001" />
    <SalesItem Item="2" PartCode="FP-0003" />
  </SalesOrder>
  <SalesOrder Id="15" Code="C1004     ">
    <Customer Code="EXBEL-LIFTS" Name="Exbel Lifts Inc." />
    <SalesItem Item="1" />
  </SalesOrder>
</SalesOrders>
```

I can control the use of elements and attributes on a column by column basis.   I can create attributes of elements to group related columns together. I can use sub-queries to generate nested elements.  You can even use functions that return XML to generate trees that are arbitrary depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FOR XML PATH` is not in the ANSI SQL-92 standard, so it will be up to the individual vendors. I do not know of any equivalent in Oracle or MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL 8.3 does not specifically have `FOR XML PATH`, but its XML functions (see [section 9.14 of the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-xml.html), particularly [9.14.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-MAPPING)) appear to provide very similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  After a quick look it seems that ProgreSQL is limited in the shape of the output XML.  FOR XML PATH provides a lot of flexibility regarding the format of the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a whole package for XML handling in it's databases.  You can even store XML straight into the database (no INSERTS ) and query it. See: [How to format xml with oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_format_output_html_xml.htm) for some examples.

Here is one of the examples:

```
    SQL> select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select employee_id, first_name,
  2  last_name, phone_number from employees where rownum < 6') xml
  3  from dual

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <EMPLOYEE_ID>100</EMPLOYEE_ID>
  <FIRST_NAME>Steven</FIRST_NAME>
  <LAST_NAME>King</LAST_NAME>
  <PHONE_NUMBER>515.123.4567</PHONE_NUMBER>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <EMPLOYEE_ID>103</EMPLOYEE_ID>
  <FIRST_NAME>Alexander</FIRST_NAME>
  <LAST_NAME>Hunold</LAST_NAME>
  <PHONE_NUMBER>590.423.4567</PHONE_NUMBER>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <EMPLOYEE_ID>104</EMPLOYEE_ID>
  <FIRST_NAME>Bruce</FIRST_NAME>
  <LAST_NAME>Ernst</LAST_NAME>
  <PHONE_NUMBER>590.423.4568</PHONE_NUMBER>
   </ROW>
  </ROWSET>
```